# Can we convert fields to/from GemFire PdxSerializer using annotations or Java Reflection?

Tags: caching, cloud-foundry, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

Currently we are using GemFire for caching.  We are in our initial phase of integrating it.

While we are working on integrating GemFire using the *Spring Data GemFire* libraries, and using GemFire's `PdxSerializer`, too, I am wondering if there is a way to convert fields to/from PDXReader/PDXWriter using basic annotations and Java Reflection.

We are using *Sprint Boot's* `2.0.3.RELEASE` JARs.

Note: I have looked at the below link:

https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/developing/data_serialization/auto_serialization.html

I am more curious how to use a non-XML way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following:

1. SDG's [`o.s.d.g.mapping.MappingPdxSerializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/mapping/MappingPdxSerializer.html) as [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.pdx-serializer).
2. Then read [how to configure it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-pdx).
3. If you are using [*Spring Boot for Pivotal GemFire*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode), then PDX is [auto-configured automatically](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#geode-data-serialization), by default, for you and you do not need to explicitly declare SDG's `@EnablePdx` annotation.

> NOTE: SDG's `MappingPdxSerializer`, when configured and registered with Pivotal GemFire, automatically de/serializes your application domain object types without any special config, like you have to do when using GemFire's own `ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer` and clumsy REGEX to identify your types properly, blah!  SDG's `MappingPdxSerializer` is much more robust, using first-class filters to express exclusions and even inclusions (which can override the default exclusions, that is any class types in `java.*`, `com.gemstone.gemfire.*`, `org.apache.geode.*` or `org.springframework.*`, by default).

Anyway...

Take 2 pills and call me in the morning - the "doc", ;-)

Comment: You are the best John :)

Comment: Thank you.  Glad that helped.